# How to force UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification in app

Tags: ios, notifications, background

I'm really not sure if we can post the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` from the app.

Suppose I have a sample app with a button and when I tap on the button it should post the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification.

Is it really possible?

Comment: You can press the home button and get this notification.

Comment: don't want to press home button.

Comment: You can post any notification you want. But should you? Probably not.

Comment: @rmaddy - want to reproduce a bug.. hence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UIApplication.shared.perform(#selector(NSXPCConnection.suspend))
```

> its working but may be its violate apple's guidline.
>
> Quitting your application or sending it to the background programmatically is a violation of the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines][1], which usually doesn't bode well for getting through the review process.

Comment: I agree.. we should not trigger programmatically, but I just need to reproduce some issue